# Angular boilerplate and Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use this project https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp but with Twitter Bootstrap 3. I find no posts on how to do that. Is it because:

1. It can't be done
2. It shouldn't be done
3. I am the only one in the world who wants to do that
4. There are other better ways to do that.

I am afraid that using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 as this boilerplate code comes with is old. Am I right?

I have tried to fix it myself but I give up the jungle world of JavaScript scripts and bugs that must be combined in a top secret order and maybe if you are lucky you don't get an error. Please help me.

Comment: It's using an extremely old version of UI-bootstrap. Looks like he could use a pull request with some much-needed updates. Maybe I'll dig into that tonight.

Comment: This is a better choice for angular+bootstrap: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular

Comment: @NathanielJohnson Does that use Twitter bootstrap 3

Comment: Yes.  And it is the preferred method.  I would also add that you will want to use Angular-Bootstrap.

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: Use it as in adding it by bower? I guess angular bootstrap supports bootstrap 3 too. Would you mind creating an answer instead of a comment? And what about angular ui?

Comment: Start with https://github.com/brnrajoriya/Angular-Ready-To-Use-Boilerplate. Best Solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I consider using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) good practice for scaffolding out new projects.  The advantage to using Yeoman is that it creates the more arcane files used by Grunt (a build tool) and Bower (a dependency management tool).  There is a [generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) for Angular. It will allow you to pick a good working set of libraries, create the project, and add more components that you find necessary later.  Yeoman is really just Grunt+Bower and then [Yo](https://github.com/yeoman/yo) - a tool for stubbing out project skeletons.  The nice thing is that you can continue to add Angular components after creating your project and it will update your config files letting you play around with the structure.

If you would like to use Bootstrap 3, I suggest looking at [Angular-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which is part of the [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) group of projects.  Angular Bootstrap contains the portion of Bootstrap that is javascript but is rewritten to use angular style directives.The CSS and icons must still be included and can be found in the normal bootstrap library. The   instructions for including the Bootstrap CSS and some great [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) examples are available in the Angular-UI readme.

**Update** Here is what a bower.json might look like. Notice that bootstrap is included separately.  This is because the bootstrap css is a separate dependency so that angular-ui does not need to be updated whenever bootstrap is.

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "ignore": [
        "**/.*",
        "node_modules",
        "lib",
        "test",
        "tests"
    ],
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "latest",
        "angular-route": "latest",
        "angular-bootstrap": "latest",
        "angular-ui-utils": "latest",
        "bootstrap": "latest",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "angular-mocks": "latest",
        "angular-scenario": "latest"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am probably stupid but I can't find any Bootstrap 3 stuff after using the angular-generator? Is this correct? What should I do after generating the project? Should I add `bower install angular-bootstrap` and `bower install bootstrap`? Am I done after that?

Comment: Yes, angular UI requires that you add the bootstrap.css file (but not the js).  The github readme has how to add it.  I just stick it in my bower.json file.  I'll give you a stub of what my bower file looks like.

Comment: I probably should have looked at your profile before I answered.  I come from a java background too and I have had a hard time transistioning to the Node/Angular javascript way of thinking.  Each tool comes with a fairly substantial learning curve and JS async code is a bitch to get used to.  I hope I cleared up this up a little but let me know and I will help as I can.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I think I managed to get it working last night. But what do you mean by bootstrap is included seperatly?

Comment: Bootstrap has three parts:  The css, the icons, and a javascript file that has the more complicated controls (like popoups, dropdowns, etc).  angular-ui-bootstrap http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ rewrites the javascript as angular directives but retains the original css and icons and does not include those files in its ditsribution.

Comment: So the CSS and icons come from the bootstrap dependency and the angular-ui rewrites the javascript file? And angular-ui does only contain the javascript? How does it know that it shall use the javascript from the angular-ui project but css and icons from the bootstrap dependency?

Comment: It doesn't.  But you specify the aspects of a project in the index.html.  That is where all the linked files go.  I recommend that you look at how grunt can help you copy and merge all the stuff together.

Comment: Ah, am I right now: The dependency on bootstrap in bower.json will download the CSS and icons but not the javascript, then a dependency on angular-ui will take the place of the bootstrap javascript when you add is a module?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.  Note: you need to manage depedencies by including the files in your main html file (index.html).  Each of these projects is distributed with a bunch of extra stuff (like tests, unminified js, alternate versions. You proabaly don't need that stuff but you will end up copying it every time.  MAnaging to copy only the files you need into a sane package is what (you guessed it) grunt does :-)

Comment: I will try it out afterwards, I think I am starting to understand how it is connected.

Comment: One thing I noticed in your bower.json file is that you miss the angular-ui dependency? Or am I wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48390/discussion-between-nathaniel-johnson-and-luckyluke)